# Dataframe query to filter using dictionary results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to filter dataframe rows using dictionary. I want all the rows where val1 > min_val_dict[user_id]  But when I run following I get error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

Here is code:

```
import pandas as pd
d={'user_id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],'val1':[101,102,103,104,105,106,107]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
min_val_dict={1:101,2:103,3:102}
df.query('val1 > @min_val_dict[user_id]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function to map column values according to a passed dictionary:

```
df[df['val1'].gt(df['user_id'].map(min_val_dict))]
```

---

```
   user_id  val1
1        1   102
3        2   104
4        2   105
5        3   106
6        3   107
```